# Searchkick Elasticsearch throwing a 400 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I recently updated to High Seirra, not sure if that means anything, and I am now getting this error when I try to reindex the Active Record Model.

Things I have tried. I have reinstalled RVM, Ruby, Elasticsearch. Still getting the same errors.

Others on my team did the same upgrade, and they are running just fine. 
Below is the error I am getting.

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Could not convert [word_start.index] to boolean"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Could not convert [word_start.index] to boolean","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Could not convert [word_start.index] to boolean","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse value [analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."}}},"status":400}
from /Users/rrobin244/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:202:in `__raise_transport_error'
```

Comment: It sounds like you are running this in a local environment (on your mac). Is your database that you are indexing different from the databases of the other members of your team? I'm guessing yes, and most likely the issue is with some data that you have locally that no one else has... now to figure out what that is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your Gemfile.lock and check the version of the elasticsearch there. If it does not match with the version of elasticsearch in your local system, delete the gemfile.lock file and run the bundle. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I had to upgrade elasticsearch on my Mac

```
brew upgrade elasticsearch
```